# How to run php file in eclipse juno

Tags: java, php, eclipse

I am new to PHP.
I am using eclipse juno. Now, I want to use PHP in my eclipse. So, I installed the PHP plugins using new software installation.

I need two things to do.

1.created a PHP project, and php file but I am not able to run the PHP file. When I try to run it, it is showing

Page load failed with error : Could not connect to server.

2.I have a project already in eclipse, I need to add a PHP file to it.
First of all is it possible or not.

I am able to create a PHP file but even here also I am not able to run the PHP file. It is not showing any output, when I run it on tomcat server. I read that I need to download php-java-bridge.war file, I downloaded it but don't know how to add to the project.

Comment: Do you have Apache or another server(NginX) capable of serve php code on your computer??

Comment: I have Apache Tomcat 7.0 server.

Comment: You can not serve php code on Tomcat(unless you use a JavaBridge or something)...to serve native php apps you need Apache Server http://httpd.apache.org/

Comment: I downloaded httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2 file. Can you help me how to add to the project.

Comment: Tell me you Operative System name and version

Comment: I am using Mac. Version OS X 10.9

Comment: Follow these instructions http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,we need to download and install the XAMP web server which is used to run the php files.

You can see how to download and installing XAMP in mac in this below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4m2k1Cmx8I

To run the PHP files, first start the MySql Database, Apache Web Server, and ProFTPD in the XAMP server. And also, we need to create the project inside the htdocs folder. If you want to run a PHP file in the existing project, you can store a copy of that project in this folder.

This will help to run the PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

To run PHP file you need a server running which understands how to handle php files.
One of the ways to do that is to run apache web server with [php installed](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php).

If you want to use tomcat and php-java-bridge.war, from what I see on their website, you probably need to create a new project from extracted war and start adding files to it.

Comment: Even that is also not working... :-( When I try to run it as PHP web application, it is showing an error that could not connect to the server.

Comment: You need to run it as J2EE application if you use php-java-bridge.war. If you don't, you need a server running with php installed

Comment: I am actually trying to do this...  http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/running_php_web_pages.htm   http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/php_servers.htm#Adding_servers  http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/adding_a_server_path_map.htm  When I try to enter URL as http://localhost, it is showing that duplicate Server URL. When I try to change it to localhost1 then it is accepting but while running the php file it is showing an error that server with host name is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I am a PHP Developer and It's better to use other IDE like Zend Studio and PHP JetStorm and as they are not free you know how to get it.You are newbie to php so I would highly recommend Zend Studio IDE as it is made from Eclipse and has the integrated debugger in it.
Just refer to this link 
[What is the best IDE for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116292/what-is-the-best-ide-for-php)