# Which is best option to display error message on the same page?

Tags: java, php, ajax, eclipse

I am new to web design. I am using eclipse IDE, Mac OS X, tomcat server and mysql database.
I created a dynamic web project. In one of my web pages, i created a login page. I am checking the username and password with the database in servlet. As I am using servlet, I need to display the error message on the new page.

I don't want to do that... Now, I want to display the error message on the same page...

While I try to know which is better for server side checking and display the message instantly, I found PHP or AJAX are best options.

But I am unable to use PHP in my project.
I installed PHP software into the eclipse... and added some code in the web.xml of the project. But not able to run the PHP file on Tomcat server.
To run the PHP files, I am using XAMP. But they are running only the PHP files not html and JSP.

Here is the issue with PHP...
   [How to run php file in eclipse juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337075/how-to-run-php-file-in-eclipse-juno)

So, please tell me which is the best option to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

this is link tutorial about create page login that it have display message errors same pages
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/
Hope, It is helpful for you