# RegExp to fix php tags

Tags: php, regex, server-migration

I made a website using php. In some places I put these php tags `<?php ?>` in other places just those `<? ?>`.

After doing a server migration the latter tags do not work because of php version differences. The new server understands only these tags `<?php ?>`.

Is there any easy regular expression that you can provide me to replace all `<? some php code here ?>` to `<?php some php code here ?>`.

Comment: Try `'#<\?(?!php)(.*?\?>)#s'` and replace with `'<?php $1'`

Comment: You can achieve this with good IDE, using it's search and replace all within a project (CTRL + H) to replace all short tags with full tags.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had to remove the # and the last s and the quotes, then it worked like a magick. Thank you very much good Sir!

Comment: @PetkoKostov any recommendations of good IDEs?

Comment: Or if your are on a Linux server : find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/<?/<?php/g' {} \; [help here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories)

Comment: @Hayk Safaryan
You can check this question and it`s answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116292/what-is-the-best-ide-for-php

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Any reason to capture the code after the opening tag?

Comment: @Jan: It is all the same without real content that I could check against. I would make my regex more context-aware if I were to use that regex based fix.

Comment: Related if not dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities here:

1. Enable the short tags with `short_open_tag=On` in `php.ini`
2. You could use a negative lookahead: `<\?(?!php)`, these needs to be replaced with `<?php`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hE6eX6/1).

Comment: Thank you very much I was not aware of short_open_tag

Comment: I had to use <\?((?!php|PHP|xml|XML|=))(.*)